# Convert several JComboBoxes, JButtons to a Set<String> in an efficient way

Tags: java, swing, collections, set, jcombobox

My program uses several JComboBoxes and JButtons to allow the users how and which data is shown. Until today I did this with many of these:

```
if (e.getSource() == someMenü_or_Button){
        if(someMenü_or_Button.getSelectedItem()=="showstuff")display.oneOfManySetter(0);            
}
```

Now I thought that I could collect all the options in a `Set<String> Attributes = new HashSet<String>();`

But the outcome in my way isn´t that more code-efficient nor has a better performance, because I do:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
attributes.clear();

if(someMenü1.getSelectedItem()== "sum"); 
else attributes.add(someMenü.getSelectedItem());
//and so on.

attributes.add(someButton1.getName());
//and so on 

//And in addition:
if (e.getSource() == someButton1){
        if(someButton1.getText()=="option1")original.setText("option2");
        else someButton1.setText("option1");
 }
```

So my Question is can I somehow convert a JComboBox into a collection and ( I know thats possible ) delete it from the set ? Then I would add again the selected Item of the JComboBox.

I know the issue with these Buttons is I should use a switch ...

EDIT 16:12

To make this rather specific a code example with what I want to do:

```
//somewhere
private Set<String> attributes = new HashSet<String>();
JComboBox<String> menu;
String[] values = {"option1","option2","option3","option4"};
panel.add (menu = new JComboBox<>(values),gbc);
menu.addActionListener(this);    

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     if(e.getSource() == menu){
           attributes.removeAll(menu.getCollection());     //HOW??????
           attributes.add(menu.getSelectedItem());
     }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a more complete example? I can't quite see any discernible pattern here. Also, the formatting is horrendous...

Comment: This is dangerous: `someMenü_or_Button.getSelectedItem()=="showstuff"`. I know that this is not your primary question, but comparing Strings with `==` is dangerous code, code that will usually break at some time since `==` and `!=`  compares if one object reference is the same as another and you don't care about this. Instead you care if the two String variables hold the same String representation, and for this use the `equals(...)` or `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` methods.

Comment: Better perhaps than using one ActionListener for all actions and then try to use switchboard logic to decide what it should do, would be to use anonymous inner class ActionListeners, and make these listeners simple, perhaps have them simply call a method of your Control class.

Comment: But even with this solution I think it would have some "elegance" to manipulate a set. And then check if some data is a sub-set of this set -> show it or not.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You mean by that something like this: `button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
        selectionButtonPressed();
      } 
    });`

Comment: As to getting items from the combo box, you can get all the items displayed from the combo box's model as it has methods that allow you to iterate through it, extracting each item. The combo box itself has a method to get an array of the selected items. Please look these up in the API as it will show you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to convert the menu. You already have the keys in the values array. Do I understand something wrong? Is this little example doing what you want to do?

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SomeClass extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private Set<String> attributes = new HashSet<>();
    private String[] values = { "a", "b", "c", "d" };
    private JComboBox<String> menu = new JComboBox<>(values);

    public SomeClass() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        init();
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SomeClass();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // attributes.add();
        if (e.getSource() instanceof JComboBox<?>) {
            JComboBox<?> menu = (JComboBox<?>) e.getSource();
            String s = (String) menu.getSelectedItem();
            attributes.removeAll(Arrays.asList(values));
            attributes.add(s);
            System.out.println(s);
            System.out.println(attributes);
        }
    }

    private void init() {
        menu.addActionListener(this);
        add(menu);
    }

}
```

Comment: Okay I think it was a dumb question, sprouting of my bad code ;)  I think your answer is correct anyway, but I specific would have to put `values` and the `menu` out of the init() .